# Embed a picture to a specific cell in an excel document by asking user to choose picture

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to embed a picture that the user selects from a selection window into a specific excel cell. The code I have follows. I want it to fit the cell dimensions, and hence will have to give the inserted picture a width and a height.
Problem: When the picture is deleted from the source file in my local computer, it gets deleted from the excel too. The code is linking the picture and not embedding it. I have tried multiple ways and failed.
The way it differs from other queries with the same question is that I want a window to pop up that allows the user to select the picture by browsing through files on the computer.
Please help.

```
Sub Insert_Picture_Loc1()
Dim rowno As Long
rowno = 30

Dim photoNameAndPath As Variant
Dim photo As Picture

photoNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Photo to Insert")
If photoNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set photo = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(photoNameAndPath)
With photo
   .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowno).Left
   .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowno).Top
   .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
   .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(2.87)
   .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & rowno).Height
   .Placement = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Shapes.AddPicture` instead of `Pictures.Insert`.